# PKCE - Code_verifier is invalid

Tags: python, python-requests, oauth, pkce

I am making a program to download certain files from a web site using python. To download I need to get access token and refresh token for that I need to pass code_verifier, but in response I'm getting : `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid Code Verifier"}`

Here is the snippinet of the code :

```
def get_token(codeverify,code,cookie):
    
    url ="https://tathya.uidai.gov.in/access/oauth/token?client_id=myAadhaar&grant_type=authorization_code&code_verifier="
    v_url= url +codeverify+"&code="+code 
    print(v_url)
    token_data ={
        'client_id':'myAadhaar',
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code_verifier': '',
        'code':''

    }
    token_data['code_verifier']=codeverify
    token_data['code']=code
    print(token_data)
    token= requests.post(v_url,data=token_data)
    print(token.status_code)
    print(token.text)
```

- v_url : url to hit
- token_data : is the payload

Here is the code to generate code verifier and code challenge:

```
import pkce


def gen(length):
    code_verifier = pkce.generate_code_verifier(96) #generates code_verifier
    code_challenge = pkce.get_code_challenge(code_verifier) #generates code_challenge 
    return code_challenge,code_verifier
```